# Importing react kendo grid inside typescript code

Tags: reactjs, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, typescript-typings

planning to add react kendo grid in existing typescript code. I tried the below imports and they failed stating cannot find modules.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Grid, GridColumn as Column } from '@progress/kendo-react-grid';
```

Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.5.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-dateinputs": "^2.7.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-dropdowns": "^2.7.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-grid": "^2.7.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-inputs": "^2.7.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-intl": "^2.7.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.5",
    "@types/jquery.ui.datetimepicker": "^0.3.29",
    "@types/jqueryui": "^1.12.6",
    "@types/node": "^10.5.5",
    "@types/react": "^16.8.6",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.8.2",

    "react": "^16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.3",

  },
```

Error:
cannot find module (ts) '@progress/kendo-react-grid'

I Tried to install them inside @types like this,
  npm install kendo-react-grid @types/@progress/kendo-react-grid

I see the Error: Invalid package name "@types/": name can only contain URL-friendly characters

What is correct way to use these imports inside .ts file?

Comment: did you try import * as KendoReactGrid from '@progress/kendo-react-grid'; and use <KendoReactGrid.Grid>, .... ?

Comment: tried but it throws same module not found.